# What does "y <- [0..]" mean?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I don't understand what `y <- [0..]` means here. Is it a variable definition?

```
f x = sum $ take 10 [x**y/product [1..y] | y <- [0..]]
```

Comment: It's part of a [list comprehension](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing#List_comprehensions).

Comment: It's an award construct to try and show, without knowing what the construct is .. but the title should probably contain _some_ example for such questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [list comprehension](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension). It can be interpreted as "for each y in [0..]".

Answer (score 0):

this means a function taking x that returns the sum of ((x to the power of y) over y factorial for y ranging from 0 to 9).